# Which tag should be used -- [table-cell] or [tablecell]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Is it [table-cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table-cell) or [tablecell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tablecell)? Each has 100-200 questions and none has a wiki.

**Edit**: *To clarify, I'm asking about HTML `<table>` tag's cells.*

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Neither. Those are terrible tags that represent all sorts of different things:

- The TableCell class in ASP.NET
- The `display: table-cell` property and value in CSS
- Cells in an Android TableLayout
- Cells in a UITableView (both iOS and Matlab)

They might as well have all just been tagged with [table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table) because either tag is just as ambiguous as that one is.

---

Ultimately, you don't need a tag for a "table cell" - you only need a tag for the type of table you're talking about, because tables encompass rows, columns, and cells. You *can't have* a table without those elements of the table, so we really don't need separate tags for each piece of the table.

For now, I retagged ~40 questions from [table-cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table-cell) to [tablecell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tablecell) and some of the other table-related tags that exist, and then merged the rest of them into [css-tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-tables) since they all referred to the CSS `display` property.

Here's a quick list of some better table tags that you should use:

- [database-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-table)
- [css-tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-tables)
- [android-tablelayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-tablelayout)
- [html-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-table)
- [uitableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uitableview)
- [qtableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qtableview)
- [matlab-uitable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab-uitable)
- [lua-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lua-table)

Please find and use the appropriate tag that actually represents the table you're working with.

Comment: This is exactly what I thought when I saw the question title XD

Answer (score 8):

From [How do I correctly tag my questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18878/how-do-i-correctly-tag-my-questions)

> - Replaces spaces with dashes (-) to combine multiple words into a single word (i.e, Tag "`Unit Testing`" as "`unit-testing`").

- If it's about a *cell* in a *table*, use [table-cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table-cell)
- [table-cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table-cell) also seems to be used for `display: table-cell;` in CSS.
- If it's about a class (like .NET's `TableCell`), use [tablecell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tablecell)

Although I'm not entirely sure if these are good tags to begin with.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer explains the need for two "similar" tags co-existence. It would be _really_ helpful, if someone wrote some wiki for these tags, so answer questions like mine.

Comment: and, if possible, add/suggest a tag wiki to either or both of the tags :) @trejder

Comment: CSS tables have a tag called [css-tables]. No idea about the rest.

Comment: Should there be an edit on the tag to replace [tag:tablecell] with [tag:asp-tablecell] to be more descriptive?